# Custom fonts not loading

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to upload Gotham fonts to a website I'm building but it's not working. I've searched on here and via google and can't see what the problem is other than a syntax upload issue that I can't spot that hopefully another pair of eyes can.

I've loaded custom fonts before on a rails app but never a pure front-end site so not sure if there's something glaring that I'm omitting. I've set up a fonts file -  Gotham_fonts - and have six files in there all with .otf extension.

**style.css**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham-Book';
  src: url('Gotham_fonts/Gotham-Book.otf') format('otf');
}

body {
  font-family: 'Gotham-Book', arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I've tried a few different variations and also tried it with `!important` but nothing. Should my fonts folder be actually inside my CSS folder?

Comment: The problem is that you are using the format string `"otf"` and it should be `"opentype"`.

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez I tried 'opentype' also and this hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: use https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator to generate OTF, TTF, EOT, and WOFF versions of your font because all four are used/preferred in certain browsers so you might as well add them all.

Secondly: Your css (your html is fine) then should look something akin to:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Gotham-Book";
    src: url("../Gotham_fonts/Gotham-Book.eot");
    src: 
    url("../Gotham_fonts/Gotham-Book.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../Gotham_fonts/Gotham-Book.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

the `../` is assuming your css folder and your 'Gotham_Fonts' folder are in the same parent directory.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: In the Font Squirrel page they have a check with *"Yes, the fonts I'm uploading are legally eligible for web embedding"* and *"Font Squirrel offers this service in good faith. Please honor the EULAs of your fonts."*. All fonts have licenses that says what is allowed to do with them (like software), you can't just use any font you have in your computer and convert it to another format, or more relevantly to this case, use it in the web if the font license doesn't allow it (well, you can, but legally is more or less the same than using pirated software).

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez Ah okay, I see. Its a client who has sent it to me and I assumed, in good faith, they'd acquired it via a full font license.

Comment: Note that the fonts can cover several cases in their licenses, [see how Gotham is offered in this site](https://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/styles/). Maybe the font you have *is* licensed for web use (you should ask the client) but is not for conversion (AFAIK almost all commercial fonts include a clause that prevent font modification for obvious reasons).

Comment: Other than the extra fonts, you should try adding `.. /` to the front of the font paths - see if that works :)

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez I think it must be the conversion that's restricted, I think the client must have purchased it at some stage as they use it quite frequently in their literature apparently.

Answer (score 3):

The code you have is mostly OK, but you used an incorrect format string:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham-Book';
  src: url('/Gotham_fonts/Gotham-Book.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

Also is important using the correct path to the font file, there are several options:

- You can use an absolute path from the root, `url('/Gotham_fonts/Gotham-Book.otf')`, this is the preferred way since it works no matter where the font file is referenced. The only downside is that if you have a test environment in which each project is a folder it will only work in production.
- You can use a relative path, but in that case you need to put it relative to the CSS file, for example, if the CSS file is the parent folder of `Gotham_fonts` you can use `url('Gotham_fonts/Gotham-Book.otf')` as you have, but if it its located e.g. in the `CSS_files` folder you have to use `url('../Gotham_fonts/Gotham-Book.otf')`.

Comment: For testing purposes I downloaded Gotham Book from, ehem, a site I found in Google (first page result), and it worked with you code after changing the format to 'opentype', so I'm almost sure that you have also a path problem. Hope that your client didn't get the font in the same way...

Comment: Could this be a bootstrap issue? Also, the fonts folder is not INSIDE my CSS folder, should it be?

Comment: In what folders do you have the different files, relative to the path? For example `Gotham_fonts` is `/Gotham_fonts` (i.e. `http://example.com/Gotham_fonts`). And the CSS/HTML?

Comment: In the console it's saying 'ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND' so this must be a path issue, right? I have the fonts folder in the same path as CSS and index.html , it has no parent folder so this path should work, right?

Comment: Yes, that error is definitely a path issue, either the directory or the file name (if you are using a Linux host check the case).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it was the files I was using (I suspect it may have been) so I tried a different font-family collection and finally got the path to work like so -

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'geomanistregular';
    src: url('../fonts/geomanist-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/geomanist-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/geomanist-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/geomanist-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/geomanist-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/geomanist-regular-webfont.svg#geomanistregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Quite a nice font actually. Thanks to all those who helped:)